# not able to create horizontal menu drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on designing a page by looking at the image I have. I am stuck on the menu bar design as I am not able to figure out how can I design the menu bar like I have in my image. It should exactly match with what I have in my image.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/1/) and here is my [image](https://s10.postimg.org/g3iy7hrsp/nm1.png) which I am trying to replicate.

I tried creating horizontal menu bar as shown in that image but somehow my menus are not showing at all. It looks like they are hidden somewhere. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="topnav">
    <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#"><b>PROGRAMS</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#"><b>WORLD OF NORTHMAN</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="#"><i>BE EXTRODINARY</i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>RISK & REWARD</i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>BLOG</i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>OUR STORY</i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="header"> <img class="header-background" src="https://s3.postimg.org/yr4kr8v0j/kaestle-chris-davenport-antarktis-2009-04.png"> <img class="orange-bar" src="https://s23.postimg.org/od4umnehn/orange-bar.png">
    <h1 class="text-inside-orange">INSURANCE FOR THE WILD</h1>
</div>
```

What is wrong I am doing here? Also I need to make `Log in | Sign up` using font aswesome (and I have already imported its css in my jsfiddle) and `GET COVERED` button as well.

Comment: Not sure, but I can tell you that even when you do get them showing, you are going to have problems on most viewports since you are using so many absolute pixel values for layout. You should be using relative units as much as possible.

Comment: Both `.dropdown` and `.dropdown-content` have `display: none`, causing them to not appear. You may want to look into a framework like [**Bootstrap's navbar template**](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/). You're also using a plethora of absolute `top` and `left` all over the place, which will cause severe problems with responsiveness.

Comment: My css have lot of things that I am not using yet but my html has only few things. I am still a beginner so still learning things. With the html I have and its corresponding css that I have, do they have any issues? If yes can you tell me wht are those and what is the best way we can resolve them. This will help me to figure out lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

The first 2 problems are:

```
.dropdown {
    display: none; /* get rid of this */
}
```

and you need your img to float: left.

Comment: Ok I tried that but everything is haywire now. Look at my updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/4/). How can I align them properly and once I click on them it shows drop down menu just below. Somehow on my page refresh everything is getting shown, I mean all the drop down elements as well. I only want to show them if I click them. Also its font and font size are very big not matching with what I have in my image.